# Displaying data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display all the data from the database I created, however it does not display all the data only the data that is recently added. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you very much!

```
<?php
  include 'dbconnect.php';
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT 
                          game_id, 
                          game_name, 
                          history_description, 
                          pl_id 
                       FROM game_post");
  $query->execute();
  $query->bind_result($game_id, $game_name, $history_description, $pl_id);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Trying</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
      while ($query->fetch()); ?>
        <article>
          <h2><?php echo $game_name; ?></h2>
          <p><?php echo $history_description; ?></p>
          <p><?php echo $pl_id ; ?></p>
        </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
while ($query->fetch()){ ?>
<article>
<h2><?php echo $game_name; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $history_description; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $pl_id ; ?></p>
</article>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?php
     $res = $query->fetch();
     while($res) {
        ?>
        <article>
            <h2><?php echo $row['game_name']; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['history_description']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $row['pl_id']; ?></p>

 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
<?php
    while($row = $query->fetch()){
        ?>
        <article>
            <h2><?php echo $row['game_name']; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['history_description']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $row['pl_id']; ?></p>
        </article>
        <?php
    }
?>
```